# Paperclip: Is that possible to recreate a deleted thumbnail without uploading the original image again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I use Paperclip like this:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :thumb => "80x80>" }, ...
```

When an image is uploaded, a thumbnail is created successfully.

Suppose, that for some reason, a thumbnail was deleted from the file system.

Is that possible to recreate the thumbnail without uploading the original image again ?

I tried:

```
Asset.find(16).save    # => true
```

but the thumbnail wasn't created in the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the reprocess! method? Something like

```
Asset.find(16).asset.reprocess!
```